# What do the binary operators mean when applied to logicals?

Tags: python

My understanding is that `&` is the bitwise AND operator. So I would expect it to have no meaning when applied to logicals. However, I see that:

```
>>> False & False
False
>>> False & True
False
>>> True & True
True
```

and so on. Likewise for the other bitwise operators.

So, why do these operators even accept logical operands? And where can I find the documentation that explains this? I searched for it but could not find an explanation.

Comment: The fact that `True` and `False` in python are effectively `1` and `0` is widely documented though...

Comment: @l4mpi So why does `True+False == 1`? As opposed to `True`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `True+False` is `1` rather than `True` because `True+True` is `2` and it makes sense to keep the types consistent.

Comment: That's because `bool` does not implement `add`. If you check the implementation in `boolobject.c` only bitwise operations are reimplemented from `int`, every other method calls the plain `int` method(which obviously returns `int`s). Probably @Blckknght is right about why they decided to implement it this way.

Comment: This is just a guess (on my phone so I can't check right now) but probably because the `__add__` method of class `bool` is inherited from `int` while the bitwise operator methods are overwritten.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So, why do these operators even accept logical operands?

`bool` subclasses `int`, and overrides `__and__()` etc to return `bool` for `bool` operands.

For details, see [PEP 285](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/).

Specifically:

```
      6) Should bool inherit from int?

       => Yes

       In an ideal world, bool might be better implemented as a
       separate integer type that knows how to perform mixed-mode
       arithmetic.  However, inheriting bool from int eases the
       implementation enormously (in part since all C code that calls
       PyInt_Check() will continue to work -- this returns true for
       subclasses of int).  Also, I believe this is right in terms of
       substitutability: code that requires an int can be fed a bool
       and it will behave the same as 0 or 1.  Code that requires a
       bool may not work when it is given an int; for example, 3 & 4
       is 0, but both 3 and 4 are true when considered as truth
       values.
```

and

```
    class bool(int):

        def __and__(self, other):
            if isinstance(other, bool):
                return bool(int(self) & int(other))
            else:
                return int.__and__(self, other)

        __rand__ = __and__

        def __or__(self, other):
            if isinstance(other, bool):
                return bool(int(self) | int(other))
            else:
                return int.__or__(self, other)

        __ror__ = __or__

        def __xor__(self, other):
            if isinstance(other, bool):
                return bool(int(self) ^ int(other))
            else:
                return int.__xor__(self, other)

        __rxor__ = __xor__
```

Note how `bool & bool` returns a `bool` whereas `bool & non-bool` inherit's `int`'s behaviour (i.e. returns an `int`).

Here are some examples demonstrating these properties:

```
In [12]: isinstance(True, int)
Out[12]: True

In [13]: True & True
Out[13]: True

In [14]: True & 1
Out[14]: 1
```

The above behaviour does not apply to arithmetic operators. Those just use `int`'s behaviour:

```
In [15]: True + 0
Out[15]: 1

In [16]: True + False
Out[16]: 1
```

Comment: However, it does not (by itself) explain why the result is `True`/`False` rather than 1/0.

Comment: Yes it does : the implementation of `__and__` function returns explicitly a bool instance

Comment: @delnan Generally operations between the same type give a result that has the same type, if possible(see overflow for `int` vs `long`). Also, doing `True & 1` returns `1` because the `True` is coerced to `int` before performing the AND.

Comment: @Boud I added my comment when the answer consisted only of what now is the first paragraph. Yes, the answer in its current form is complete and good (and in fact I upvoted it).

Comment: By the way, the implementation shown is not actually the class really used, it's just an example that show the properties that `bool` should have. The real implementation can be seen in `Objects/boolobject.c` and follows the same pattern, using C-API calls.

Comment: Thank you very much. Alles clar.

Answer (score 0):

"Logicals", aka booleans, just represent a single bit either on or off, so of course bitwise operations work on them.  What would make you expect bitwise operations not work on single bits?

You're inverting the inheritance of logical operations.  The base case of bitwise operations is on single bit variables such as booleans.  Bitwise operations on larger values are just an extended application of the single bit operation.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.x True and False are keywords and will always be equal to 1 and 0.

Under normal circumstances in Python 2, and always in Python 3:

False object is of type bool which is a subclass of int:

```
 object
  |
 int
  |
 bool
```

Comment: Slightly misleading. `True` and `False` are actually singletons that aren't the integers 1 and 0, though `bool` indeed inherits from `int`, they are considered equal, and are treated as these numbers for most numeric operations.

Comment: Tried in my interpretor
>>> 1 == True
True

Comment: As I said, they are considered equal. They are of distinct types though, and no integer object with value 0 or 1 is identical to True and False. On the other hand, equality has no effect on bitwise operators, so it's of little relevance here.

Comment: @fyre delnan is right and it's actually easy to prove that they're distinct objects: `True is 1` and `1 is True` both return.. False.